# How to approve a record with in a email itself

Tags: apex, community, email, salesforce1-app, approval-process

Hi friends i'm new to development.I got a requirement to approve a record on a certain basis.So, we create an approval process for that.

But now i got a requirement like the record needs to be approved with in the reply of the email in approval request.

Like,we sent an email for approval request.
So,If approver says **Approved** the record needs to be updated.

Please suggest me is there any possibility to achieve above requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **Enable Email Approval Response** Under: `Set up -> Create -> Workflow & Approvals -> Process Automation Settings.`

Please follow this Salesforce documentation on how to do this.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_email.htm&language=en_US

Also check this link for step by step explanation 
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/06/approval-through-email-in-salesforce.html